# ActiveRecord::Base#create - TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have

```
class CreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration 
  def change
    create_table :roles do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :members, :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :content, :title, :role_id
  belongs_to :role
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :lockable

  attr_accessible :role_id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
end
```

In the Rails console or in seeds.rb, I type

```
Role.create(name: 'guest')
```

and get the error

```
TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/builder/collection_association.rb:35:in `[]'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/builder/collection_association.rb:35:in `wrap_block_extension'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/builder/collection_association.rb:22:in `build'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb:139:in `build'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/builder/has_many.rb:10:in `build'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/builder/collection_association.rb:13:in `build'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations.rb:1195:in `has_many'
    from /Users/ataylo9/Dropbox/Developer/hamsterdam/app/models/role.rb:3:in `<class:Role>'
    from /Users/ataylo9/Dropbox/Developer/hamsterdam/app/models/role.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:469:in `block in load_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:639:in `new_constants_in'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:468:in `load_file'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:353:in `require_or_load'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:502:in `load_missing_constant'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:192:in `block in const_missing'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `each'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activesupport-3.2.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:190:in `const_missing'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

I know I get the error because Rails wants to build the relationship for Members and Posts, but shouldn't it just make those nil. I even tried explicitly setting the arrays to nil in seeds.rb, but got the same error.

What am I failing to understand? Thanks!

**UPDATED: Added Post and Member model for reference**

Answer (score 3):

I created the same project with the same models. And what I found out this kind of description relations occurs that error.

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :members, :posts
end
```

I tried this:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :members
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :role_id
  belongs_to :role
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :role_id
  belongs_to :role
end
```

And everything works. I don't know why but looks like has_many :posts, :members occurs the problem. But you can write in different way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

jizak's answer is what helped push me in the right direction, in terms of finding the solution to my own problem.  At first, I was trying to add multiple 'items' to a single has_many, as in the above example:

> has_many :members, :posts

My Rails console game me the same error - "TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer." So I split it up onto two different lines:

> has_many :members
>   has_many :posts

And now it works fine.

I guess I was trying to be a little too clever, thinking associations (has_many) would be similar to attr_accessor/writer/reader - where one can add multiple things to a single attr_x (or in this case, has_many).  This is not the case with Rails (as far as I know) - each association needs its own individual declaration.

Comment: This helped be with my `TypeError: can't convert Symbol into Integer`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you assigned relations (has_many :members, :posts) which doesn't exist. Do you have such models? Do models have such relations? Can you post code of Member and Post model?

Comment: I added them in the question. Thanks!

Comment: I experienced an issue with declaring multiple `has_many` relations in a single line. Please see reference the answer by @jizak below, which helped me identify this issue